# Can I pass around mgp.ProcCtx and implement parallel graph algorithms in Python that use the actual graph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I am using Memgraph Platform 2.6.4 which includes MAGE 1.5.1. I noticed that MAGE has an [interesting part of the code](https://github.com/memgraph/mage/blob/main/python/mage/graph_coloring_module/algorithms/meta_heuristics/parallel_algorithm.py) that tells me that you can use multiprocessing on the server. But, can I pass around `mgp.ProcCtx` and implement parallel graph algorithms in Python which use the actual graph, or do I need to work on graph representations like in [this example](https://github.com/memgraph/mage/blob/6d27c9be4304dd127004637c2b4f7cec3bc3aabd/python/graph_coloring.py#L146)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass around `mgp.ProcCtx` object to functions and work on them in multiprocessing way. But what you can't do is write to Memgraph changes on that processing graph in multiprocessing way.